# If $\lim f(x) = \lim g(x)$ everywhere, does it imply $f = g$ everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove or disprove the statement:

> If $f, g ∶\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are functions such that
> $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$
> for any $a\in \mathbb R$, then $f = g$.

I think the statement is false, since it is not given that $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

On the other hand, it states that it works for any $a\in\mathbb R$, making it hard to find a counterexample.

Can anyone enlighten me on this issue?

Comment: Take your favorite example of a discontinuous function which is defined everywhere, which has a limit everywhere, but for which the limit does not equal the function at some point.  Build a counterexample out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disproof.
Let $f(x) = 0$ everywhere.
Let $g(x) = 0$ except for $x=0$, where $g(0)=1$.

$$\forall a\quad \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$$
But $f(0) \ne g(0)$.